# Insert same data into PostgreSQL and MySQL simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I use ROR with postgreSQL (for Ipad App) and PHP with MySQL (for Web App) for the same project. How can I insert values into these two databases simultaneously? I mean, when a user registers with Ipad App, the data should be inserted to both PostgreSQL and MySQL db and vice versa. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `ROR` and `PHP` script with data simultaneously.....

Comment: Can one of the projects be refactored so they use a common database? Or, if not, perhaps have an offline process that copies records from one to another - each record has a `created_at` and an `updated_at`, and you use this to sync changes in either direction that you have not already copied.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the DB from rails, make your rails script run a php script on the server which would be simply a model to insert the data. You can call the php script with an http request and POST the values you need. That's how I would do it, I'm not sure if there are any better ways, since, as far as I know, you can only use 1 db driver for each project with rails.

Or, you can change your rails project to use the same database as the PHP script, but you'd need to create the project with `rails new ProjectName -d mysql`